# py.test "import file mismatch" despite different names (only Windows)

Tags: pytest

I am fairly new to py.test and have tried to set up a couple of simple black box tests for some legacy code. The directory structure looks somewhat like this:

```
X:\
   conftest.py
   prgm_A\
      src\
      test\
         test_A.py
   prgm_B\
      src\
      test\
         test_B.py
```

When I run py.test from X:\, using py.test v. 2.6.3 in Windows 7 (or XP), py.test returns the following type of error message:

```
___________ ERROR collecting /prgm_A/test/test_A.py __________________
import file mismatch:
imported module 'test_A' has this __file__ attribute:
  X:\prgm_A\test\test_A.py
which is not the same as the test file we want to collect:
  X:\\prgm_A\test\test_A.py
HINT: remove __pycache__ / .pyc files and/or use a unique basename for 
your test file modules
<and the same for B>
```

I have removed the __pycache__ and .pyc files, but that did not work. That extra backslash after the drive letter looks really fishy, but I am quite sure I am not to blame for that.

When I try to run the same tests in linux (despite the fact that the programs are compiled for windows), py.test v. 2.5.1 does not have the same problem.

My workaround until now has been to run the tests for each individual program from its own test directory, but after our computers were migrated to Windows 7, this stopped working.

Any ideas?

---

#### Additional Facts/Observations

1. I forgot to say that the tests used to work under XP, with an earlier py.test?, provided that I stepped down to X:\prgm_[AB]\test and ran py.test from there.
2. Superstition: Inserting one extra level in the file structure, moving everything from X:\ to X:\one_extra_level, didn't make one bit of a difference.
3. I have managed to reproduce the problem with this minimal example:

   ```
   # conftest.py:
   import pytest

   def returns_xyz():
       return "xyz"

   @pytest.fixture(scope="session")
   def provider():
   """Provides a subprogram which returns the string 'xyz'."""
       return returns_xyz

   # prgm_[AB]\test\test_[AB].py:
   import pytest
   def test_xyz(provider):
       assert "xyz" == provider()
   ```

Comment: Hmmm I couldn't reproduce the problem on my Windows 7 computer, either with pytest 2.6.4 nor 2.6.3. Does it work if you run `py.test x:\prgm_A x:\prgm_B`?

Comment: With X:\ as the current working directory, i.e. "standing in X:\", the commands `py.test prgm_A` and `py.test prgm_B` worked just fine. However, stepping down into X:\prgm_[AB]\test and running `py.test` sans arguments, makes py.test complain that it cannot find the fixture "provider". This is a second issue which has showed up after our migration to Windows 7, something which I think should be the topic of another stackoverflow question.

Comment: I could reproduce the problem now, I had to use `subst` to create a virtual drive. I also discovered that if I move `prgm_A` and `prgm_B` to a new subdirectory, say `X:\src`, executing `py.test X:\src` works, while `py.test X:\ ` still fails. I think there is a bug on how pytest is constructing paths when one of the paths in the command line is the root of a drive letter, because even if I have `x:\prgm_A` and `X:\prgm_B`, executing `py.test prgm_A prgm_B` works.

I suggest reporting a but in the official [issues page](https://bitbucket.org/pytest-dev/pytest/issues?status=new&status=open).

Answer (score 1):

Everything you need for resolving this issue is to remove the python path file. It's a file with this extension `.pyc` and remove also the folder `__pycache__` if it's available on your test or project.

Lamine

Answer (score 1):

As explained [here](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/702#issuecomment-310661735), you just have to add an `__init__.py` file in your test folder and it will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

the issue moved to https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/702

this is not a bug, as far as i can tell the python module name is the same for both test modules

py.test complains about different files ending up with the same module name, thus breaking details

can you verify?

*edit*

its been verified as bug

Answer (score -1):

Delete all .pyc file in your project directory
Execute Command : find . -name *.pyc -delete

It worked for me!

Comment: Do please go through the question properly before posting an answer. The question states that the user had already tried deleting .pyc files.